# String index out of range and I can't fix the error

Tags: python-3.x

So below is my code.  Somewhere in the "for digit in observed" loop there is an indexing error that I can't seem to find or fix.  I believe it's something to do with the PINS list, but I'm not sure, as none of my edits have made a difference.  Test case that fails is observed = '11'.  Single cases all pass.  Unfortunately as I'm using codewars, there is no line given for the error, just the following:

Traceback:

in

in get_pins

IndexError: string index out of range

```
def get_pins(observed):

    # Let's see what we're working with
    print("observed")
    print(observed)
    print(" ")

    # Dictionary of possible numbers for a half-assed observation of a key press.
    possible = {'0':'08','1':'124','2':'1235','3':'236', 
                '4':'1457','5':'24568','6':'3569',
                '7':'478','8':'05789','9':'689'}

    # Single digit pwd case
    PINS=[]

    if len(observed) == 1:
        for digit in possible[observed]:
            PINS.append(digit)
        return PINS

    # Find number of possible PINs
    num_possibles = 1
    # Step through observed digits
    for digit in observed:
        num_possibles*=len(possible[digit])

    # Populate PINS to allow string manipulation
    PINS = " "*num_possibles
    print(PINS[num_possibles])
    num_change = num_possibles
    change = []
    count = 0

    # Step through observed, determine change of digit, 
    for digit in observed:

        # Last digit in observed means it iterates every time
        if digit != observed[len(observed)-1]:

            # Develop array for checking position
            num_change = num_change/len(possible[digit])

            for i in range(1,len(possible[digit])):
                change.append(i*num_change)

            print(change)

            # Populate PINS with possible digit, full pin is created after final iteration of digit/observed loop
            for pin in range(0,num_possibles-1):
                PINS[pin] = PINS[pin] + possible[digit][count]
                if (pin+1) in change:
                count+=1       
            change=[]
            count =0
        else:
            for pin in range(0,num_possibles-1):
                PINS[pin] = PINS[pin] + possible[digit][count]
                count+=1
                if count == len(possible[digit]):
                    count = 0

  return PINS
```

Comment: Please be more informative. What line throws the error? What is the actual error message? Also, it would help if you turned this into a [mcve] by providing a sample input for `observed`, one that illustrates the problem.

Comment: Have added edits @JohnColeman

Comment: It would still help if you gave a sample of an `observed` input, together with what the intended output would be.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
PINS = " "*num_possibles
print(PINS[num_possibles])
```

The first line creates a string of spaces of length `num_possibles`. This means that the valid indices are `0, 1, ..., num_possibles - 1`. However, in the very next line you try to index the string at the non-existent index `num_possibles`.

I would simply drop that `print`. What is the point of it? You know that `PINS` is a string of all spaces, so why bother?

Strings are immutable, since `PINS` is a string, the line

```
PINS[pin] = PINS[pin] + possible[digit][count]
```

would trigger the error:

```
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

What you should do is to initialize `PINS` as

```
PINS = [' ']*num_possibles
```

Or, probably even better

```
PINS = ['']*num_possibles
```

In which case

```
PINS[pin] = PINS[pin] + possible[digit][count]
```

would be legal (although it could be shortened by use of `+=`) -- although I'm not sure if this is what you really want to do since you are concatenating the strings stored as values in the `possible` and not adding the numbers represented by those strings.

At the end of the function, replace `return PINS` by `return`''.join(PINS)`

That will fix some of your bugs, but since I know neither intended input nor intended output I can't say any more.